# Hide 0 values in Stacked Column Chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to remove the 0-values from my stacked column chart in Highcharts. Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4NxYh/

At "15.08." you see the top most value as "0" which is very confusing. How can i hide this?

How can i hide "low" values like the top most "1" on "14.08." so that it doesn't overflow the area?

This is the code that i'm using:

```
chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["14.08","15.08","16.08","17.08","18.08","19.08","20.08","21.08","22.08","23.08","24.08","25.08","26.08","27.08","28.08"] 
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            endOnTick: false,
            maxPadding: 0.0,
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            },
            allowDecimals: false
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 0,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Gesamt: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                },
                treshold: 1
            }
        },
        series: [{"name":"a","data":[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],"_colorIndex":0},{"name":"b","data":[92,91,65,56,102,146,146,86,117,115,103,108,137,134,19],"_colorIndex":1},{"name":"c","data":[13,4,3,1,5,13,2,4,2,2,3,3,2,8,0],"_colorIndex":2},{"name":"d","data":[3,6,1,4,3,6,3,2,1,6,3,3,0,6,1],"_colorIndex":3},{"name":"e","data":[41,19,8,16,30,32,46,19,17,11,15,13,52,30,2],"_colorIndex":4},{"name":"f","data":[5,2,3,2,5,3,4,2,3,2,1,3,4,12,1],"_colorIndex":5},{"name":"g","data":[70,80,77,72,77,94,80,60,52,75,49,84,74,72,12],"_colorIndex":6},{"name":"h","data":[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],"_colorIndex":7},{"name":"i","data":[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],"_colorIndex":8},{"name":"j","data":[0,0,2,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,4,2,1,0],"_colorIndex":0},{"name":"k","data":[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"_colorIndex":1}] 
    };
container = $('#chart');
container.highcharts(chartOptions);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use label.formatter, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/4NxYh/4/

```
            formatter: function(){
                var val = this.y;
                if (val < 6) {
                    return '';
                }
                return val;
            },
```

Comment: That did the trick. But i adjusted this with `if(this.y/this.total < 0.05)` to check not an absolute value, but the percentage. so in this example, i hide values, when they are less than 5%